# Displaying data from multiple models on one view (images and text)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi everyone so I am trying to create an application using asp.net mvc with a code first database that allows the users to be able to create a blog post with as many images as they wish.I have the data stored in the database but I I am currently trying to have the the head, body and images displaying in the display view this is what I would like it to look like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFfyI.jpg but I am not sure how to accomplish this. I am able to display the head and body but cannot get the images from the image table here is the database diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2z4o.jpg

Currently this is the error I get  when i add this to the view         `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Images)`

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

Model

```
public partial class PostModel
{
    public PostModel()
    {
        Images = new List<ImageModel>();
    }
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Heading is Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Heading")]
    public string Heading { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Body is Required")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Body")]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ImageModel> Images { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> File { get; set; }
}

public class ImageModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public virtual PostModel Post { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
public class ImageVM
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
public partial class PostVM
{
    public PostVM()
    {
       Images = new List<ImageVM>();
    }

    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Heading { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
    public List<ImageVM> Images { get; set; }

}
```

DbContext

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{    
    public DbSet<PostModel> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PostVM> PostVMs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ImageModel> Images { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ImageVM> ImageVMs { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
 public ViewResult Display()
 {
        return View(repository.Posts) 
  }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<Crud.Models.PostModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
     <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Heading)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Body)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Images)
        @*<img class="img-thumbnail" width="150" height="150" src="/Img/@item.Images" />*@
    </div>

}
```

Here is alternative controller I tried but am not using as I got this error when i tried let  `Images = i.Path` and wasn't really sure if this was meant to be how it was done

> Cannot implicity convert typeCrud 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List  Crud.Models.ImageVm '

```
  public ViewResult Display()
        {

            IEnumerable<PostVM> model = null;
            model = (from p in db.Posts
                     join i in db.Images on p.ID equals i.Post
                     select new PostVM
                     {
                         ID = p.ID,
                         Heading = p.Heading,
                         Body = p.Body,
                         Images = i.Path
                     });
            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item.Images` is a collection. So loop through that and display the images.

```
<div>
    @foreach(var image in item.Images)
    {
       <img src="@image.Path" />
    }       
</div>
```

You need to make changes to the `src` property depending on what value you store in the `Path` property of image.

You can correct your other action method like this

```
public ViewResult Display()
{
    var posts = db.Posts.Select(d => new PostVM()
    {
        ID = d.ID ,
        Heading  = d.Heading,
        Body = d.Body,
        Images = d.Images.Select(i => new ImageVM() { Path = i.Path, 
                                                      DisplayName = i.DisplayName }
                                ).ToList()
    }).ToList();
    return View(posts);
}
```

Now since you are returning a list of `PostVM`, make sure your Display view is strongly typed to that.

```
@model List<PostVM>
<h1>Posts</h1>
@foreach(var p in Model)
{
  <h3>@p.Heading</h3>
  <p>@p.Body</p>
  @foreach(var image in item.Images)
  {
    <img src="@image.Path" />
  }
}
```

Also, there is no point in keeping the view model classes on your db context. Keep only your entity models. View models are only for the use of UI layer.

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{    
    public DbSet<PostModel> Posts { get; set; }   
    public DbSet<ImageModel> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: for some reason that gives me a not supported exception ? >The entity or complex type 'Crud.Concrete.PostVM' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: updated my view like you said but for some reason it gives me a not supported exception ? >The entity or complex type 'Crud.Concrete.PostVM' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query. on the last tolist in the display method in the controller

Comment: @WellThisIsAkward You should remove the view models from the db context class. See the update.